# Deploy web pages with self hosted Parse

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I have deployed a Parse server on AWS. I intend to host an admin page where we can view some stats and Post some data. Since The parse is a NodeJS application I tried sending a Post request from an HTML form like below.

```
<form action="/abc" method="post" >
```

However when we submit form the parameters are not passed in the below post method which is written in the **index.js** file.

```
app.post('/abc', function (req, res) { 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the [parse js sdk](https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/js/guide/) to get your data.  Building and processing forms is doable, but parse has a great client side library that will help you build a secure ui, why not use it?

But to answer your question directly, which is really an express question, not a parse question:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// application/x-www-form-urlencoded which is what a browser will
// send when a form is posted.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get('/abc', (req, res) => {
  const s = '<form action="/abc" method="post" >'
  + '<input name="say" value="hello" />'
  + '<button>Send it!</button>'
  + '</form>';
  res.send(s);
});

app.post('/abc', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('ok');
});
```